# How I can prove that: If $X$ is compact, then any map $f\colon X \to Y$ is proper?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

A continuous map $f\colon X \to Y$ of locally compact spaces is called proper if for any compact $C\subset Y$ the preimage $f^{-1}(C)$ is compact. My **question** is: How I can prove that: If $X$ is compact, then any map $f\colon X\to Y$ is proper?

Comment: It appears that *locally compact* includes the Hausdorff condition for you. Hint: Observe that compact subsets of a Hausdorff space are closed and continuity can be defined via closed sets. // What does this have to do with finite groups and abelian groups?

Comment: @Martin: I do not speak about groups!.

Comment: But [you used the tags](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/382131/1) (finite-groups) and (abelian-groups). I asked why :-)

Comment: @Martin: This is from the precedent question!.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming $Y$ is Hausdorff, if $C$ is compact then it is closed. So $f^{-1}(C)$ is closed and any closed subspace of a compact space is compact.

Comment: I think that a compact $C ⊂ Y$ need not be closed if $Y$ is not hausdorff.

Comment: @K.Stm. You are correct, I'll edit.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**:
Assume $Y$ to be hausdorff.
Then use that preimages under a continuous map of closed subsets are closed.

As pointed out by StefanH. and Martin in the comments, what you really need is compact subsets of $Y$ to be closed therein, which holds in hausdorff spaces.
Locally compact spaces are usually assumed to be hausdorff.

Here’s an example where the criterion fails if $Y$ if compact subsets of $Y$ are not necessarily closed:

Take $Y = \{0,1\}$ with the trivial topology.
And let $f : [0..1] → Y$ be the indicator function on $(0..1)$.
Since the only open subsets of $Y$ are $∅$ and $Y$ itself, clearly $f$ is continuous, but $f^{-1}(\{1\}) = (0..1)$ is not compact, whereas singletons are definitely compact.

Comment: Nice answer. Is "concrete topology" = "trivial topology" = "indiscrete topology", i.e., the only open sets are the empty set and the full space?

Comment: @Martin – trivial topolgy, yes. I thought it was called “concrete”.

Comment: It was rather clear from the context, but I've never seen it used that way. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, $Y$ Hausdorff is not necessary. What you need is the property that compact subsets are closed, and there are non-Hausdorff spaces where this holds.

Comment: @StefanH. True, I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: An easy example of a non-Hausdorff space in which compact sets are closed is the cocountable topology on an uncountable set. The compact sets are precisely the finite sets.